# I need load capacitors on crystal?

Tags: capacitor

Using external PLL clock Multiplier ICS501A

The crystal is http://www.txccrystal.com/images/pdf/ab-automotive.pdf

I need load capacitors on crystal ?

Comment: Is your question about the fact that the formula in the ICS501A suggests your load capacitance would be 0pF if your crystal load cap is 12pF?  If so, then state that, otherwise it's obvious from the data sheet formula what the load capacitance should be (see page 3).

Comment: You really haven't added anywhere near enough detail here - crystal frequency? Link to ICS501A datasheet? Have you looked in the datasheet even?

Comment: People say yes. People say no. People say its obvious.

Comment: @user83406  People also say you should have done due diligence before posting the question here.  [Welcome to EE.SE, by the way.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the load capacitance required for the crystal and the ICS501A datasheet indicates that zero is required for a 12pF crystal you don't actually need any additional capacitance.

However I would put the locations for the capacitors on the PCB but leave them unstuffed (i.e. don't populate any capacitors).  If for some reason you do need extra capacitance or you have to change your crystal supplier to one that needs more capacitance then you are covered without having to spin the PCB.

The sort of problems you might have is that the frequency is slightly incorrect (eg a bit high) or the oscillator does not start reliably.  In those cases you may need to experiment with adding capacitance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, typically.

With the clarifications to the question, and responses from others, it appears that the specific IC crystal driver in question contains sufficient load capacitance and/or compensates for a 12pF load.

However, I strongly agree with @SpehroPefhany as he writes eloquently about this topic:

> In my opinion, it would be prudent to put a couple 0402 caps in the
>   schematic/layout anyway (marked DNP - do not populate), just in case
>   you have to use a crystal with a higher load specification at some
>   time in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is right on the [ICS501A datasheet](https://www.idt.com/document/dst/loco-pll-clock-multiplier).

[image]

Since your [crystal datasheet](http://www.txccrystal.com/images/pdf/ab-automotive.pdf) says the default load the crystals are designed for is 12pF, then you don't need them (unless the load capacitance of the crystal you bought is other than the default 12pF, in which case use the formula above). If the crystal was designed for less than 12pF then you probably shouldn't use it.

[image]

In my opinion, it would be prudent to put a couple 0402 caps in the schematic/layout anyway (marked DNP - do not populate), just in case you have to use a crystal with a higher load specification at some time in the future.

To tell what crystals you have (or should order) refer to the [part numbering system](http://txccrystal.com/images/pdf/number-crystal-automotive.pdf) for this vendor:

[image]